# Transform transitions not working when combined with width changes

Tags: css, flexbox, webkit, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I'm working on this mobile menu where you can expand and collapse different categories. When doing so, a sliding animation should be performed on the expanded submenu (when expanding) or on the top-level menu (when collapsing).

The structure of the HTML is the following:

```
<div class="slideOpenMainMenu">
    <div class="sideMenuGeneral">
        ...Top-level menu...
    </div>
    <div class="sideMenuPanelMainChildren">
       ...Expanded submenu...
    </div>
</div>
```

By adding and removing classes, I show the appropriate div while hiding the other from view. As you'll notice, I go out of my way to not use anything like `display:none;` since then I won't be able to animate the containers. Instead I use a combination of width, height, visibility and flex properties to hide and show the containers.

```
/* Menu parent container */
.slideOpenMainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #12416e 0%, #0d3050 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Top-level menu - Initial state */

.sideMenuGeneral {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 620px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 20px 16px 0 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* item submenu - Initial state */

.sideMenuPanelMainChildren {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  flex: 0 1 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

/* Top-level menu - Expanded state */

.slideOpenMainMenu.item-expanded .sideMenuGeneral {
  width: 0%;
  padding: 0 !important;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slideOpenMainMenu.item-expanded .sideMenuPanelMainChildren {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

For the animation, I use `transform:translateY` and `opacity` properties to create the sliding effect I want.

```
/* Initial state */
.slideOpenMainMenu .sideMenuPanelMainChildren {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30%);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease, visibility 0s ease;
}

.slideOpenMainMenu .sideMenuGeneral {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease, visibility 0s ease;
}

/* Expanded state */

.slideOpenMainMenu.item-expanded .sideMenuPanelMainChildren {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slideOpenMainMenu.item-expanded .sideMenuGeneral {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

As you can see on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/handfulofcats/uLvocryb), the animation works well in Chrome and Firefox. Not so well on Webkit and Edge. From what I can tell, there seems to be some kind of conflict between the change in width and the transitions, because when I disable changes in width, you can see the animation play out. What could cause the change in behavior between platforms? Is there a way to correctly sequence the changes?

Answer (score 0):

So while writing this question, I arrived at the answer (as it often happens). The issue seems to be rooted in that the sequence of CSS property changes is different on different browsers. by adding a tiny delay (0.01s) to the transform transition I got it to work, like so:

```
transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease 0.01s, visibility 0s ease;
```

Still, I find this a little odd and also interesting. If anyone has info on how these things are sequenced in the browser that'd be really great to learn.